# Doing calculation with NSDecimalNumber or Float

Tags: objective-c, floating-accuracy, nsdecimalnumber

I have to do calculation in my application, i have formules like this one :

```
result = Capital * rate / (1- 1/(1+ rate)^frequence)
```

I have read in internet that doing calculation with floats can be lossless.

Should i use NSDecimalNumber in my situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All numbers, including `NSDecimalNumber` have only a specific accuracy.
Floats and Doubles are binary representation of numbers and they can represent 23 and 52 binary digits respectively (about 7 and 16 decimal digits).

That means that some numbers cannot be represented precisely. For example, consider `1 / 3` - to be represented precisely, you would need an infinite number of digits (`0.333333333333...`).

In most situations 16 decimal digits is more than enough, especially when the result of a calculation doesn't have to be absolutely accurate. The precision can be also affected by the order of calculations.

`NSDecimalNumber` can hold up to about 30 decimal digits (it doesn't represent numbers in binary), so it can hold numbers more precisely than a Double. However, calculations with `NSDecimalNumber` are not done natively on CPU and are much slower. It's not something you want to do if speed is necessary. We use `NSDecimalNumber` mainly for calculations with currency because we need high precision there (especially we want to avoid precision loss when converting to binary and back).

Comment: Thanks. If i want 16 digits précision, is the use of floats or NSDecimalNumber will give exactly the same results ?

Comment: @samir Nope. One will calculate in decimal, one in binary. The conversion from decimal to binary and back will make a difference. Also, you can't really enforce exactly 16 bit precision.